# Can't get array to display values that match between two methods

Tags: java

I have 3 methods. The first does the brunt of the work and contains 10 values within an array. The second methods sole purpose is to create an array that contains 5 values that differ from those within the first method. The final method is supposed to compare both of these and then display those values that match between the two (which there shouldn't be any values that match). I have found several questions already that ask about comparing two arrays and displaying either a true or false, and in using these methods have been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also understand that .length means the arrays need to be the same length in order for the comparison to occur however, how do I compare them without them being the same length?

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class ArrayMethodDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Numbers in numerical order are:");
        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x)
            System.out.println(numbers[x]);
        System.out.println("Numbers in reverse order are:");
        for(int x = numbers.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            System.out.println(numbers[x]);
        System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is:");
        int sumNumbers = IntStream.of(numbers).sum();
            System.out.println(sumNumbers);
        System.out.println("All numbers less than 6 are:");
        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x)
        {
            if(numbers[x] < 6)
            {
                System.out.println(numbers[x]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All numbers higher than the average value 5.5 are:");
        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[x];
        }
        double average = 1.0d * sum / numbers.length;
        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
        {
            if(numbers[x] > average)
            {
                System.out.println(numbers[x]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All numbers that are similar between both arrays are:");
        System.out.println(compareArrays());
    }
    public static int[] newNumbers()
    {
        int[] newNumbers = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
        return newNumbers;
    }
    public static void compareArrays(int[] numbers, int[] newNumbers)
    {
        boolean b = true;
        for(int x = 0; x < newNumbers.length; x++) 
        {
            if(newNumbers[x] == numbers[x])
            {
                b = true;
            }
            else
            {
                b = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First: you call compareArrays() method inside a print statement and your method does't return a value to print.

second: you did't calll compareArrays() method with any parameters when you should because it has two parameters specified and without parameter your compare will not find values to compare.

I think your code should be like this:

```
 System.out.println(compareArrays(numbers));

public static boolean compareArrays(int[] numbers)
    {
        boolean b = true;
        int[] newNumbers = newNumbers();

        for(int x = 0; x < newNumbers.length; x++) 
        {
            if(newNumbers[x] == numbers[x])
            {
                b = true;
            }
            else
            {
                b = false;
            }
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Comment: That worked! Now my only question is, how do I get the follow up to the System.out.println to say 'there are none' instead of 'false'?

Comment: Instead of (return b;) you can write if (!b) { return "there are none"} else { return "there are";} and change the return type of the method to be string

Comment: This is certainly badly wrong.  What it returns is the result of the very last comparison - that is, whether `newNumbers[newNumbers.length - 1]` matches `numbers[newNumbers.length - 1]`.  If the idea is to compare the arrays, this method should return `false` as soon as a discrepancy is found, otherwise there'll be far too many false positives.

Comment: Indeed, this traverses every element and sets the final result to the comparison of the last two elements. It also doesn't deal with arrays of different lengths like they ask.